# How to fix: @ in regular expression of perl script interpreted as array

Tags: javascript, html, regex, perl, cgi

I have the following java script function in my perl document:

```
function emailcheck()
{
  var emailoutline = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
  var x = document.ec.email.value;
  if (emailoutline.test(x))
  {
    alert("valid email");  
  }
}
```

that is part of a 
      print html
block so I think it should work fine. The html part works fine if I use it outside of the perl document, but once I link it there, it does not work anymore. The "@" in the regular expression is also marked green while all the rest of the html part of the script is marked red - I think the problem is that the "@" is interpreted by perl as the beginning of an array. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem?

This is the whole code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<'HTML';
<html>
<head>
<title>Mailcheck</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="ec" action ="">
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
  <input type="button" value="Pruefen" onclick="javascript:emailcheck();">
  </form>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function emailcheck()
  {
    var emailoutline = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+\@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    var x = document.ec.email.value;
    if (emailoutline.test(x))
    {
      alert("This is a valid eMail");  
    }
    else
    {
      alert("This is not a valid eMail");
    }
  }
  </script>
 </body>
HTML
exit;
```

Comment: Escape means putting a backslashe before the character, like `\@`. In regex we can also express characters by its ascii code, you can also try using `\x40` instead of `@` *(40 is the HEX equivalent to "@" in [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif))*

Comment: I have now put in the whole code - the edits you suggested solved the problem, that the "@" is not marked in green anymore but the code is still not working - Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Perhaps it's better to put the JavaScript into a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own:

I had to rewrite the regular expression like this:

```
var emailoutline = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+\@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\$\/\;
```

since perl cut of the reserved symbols "$" and "/". Now the code is working fine - Just wanted to post the solution if someone else ever comes across the same problem. Thank you for all the help though :)

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, `@` is a reserved character. You need to escape it (`\@`) to avoid being interpreted as an array sigil.

Comment: Thanks for the post, however, it is still not working so I posted the whole code above - maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: oops that just got missing due to copy pasting from my file... thanks for pointing it out though. it did not solve the problem sadly :/

Comment: As you can see from the example link I posted, I copy and pasted your code and it works

Comment: Well, thats the problem. The html code alone also works for me - it just does not work when linked in perl document like i did it above...

Comment: Do you have the right properties set on your script?

Comment: yes - the perl script is working, it also shows the form and the button and everything, the only problem is that the function call does not work in the perl script. it does work when i simply use the html code though :/

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-interpolating print to prevent Perl from attempting to expand variables:

```
print <<'HTML';
...
HTML
```